# using my editText i want to see saved list of items from my arraylist and display a couple of lines of detail about the item

Tags: java, android

i have EditText and two buttons(SAVE & EDIT). how do i use the edittext to list a list of item which i want to create in a ArrayList. the edittext will give me the stored items, save button will give me the opportunity to save any item i want to save in the array and edit button will give me the opportunity to  update existing item. thanks a lot for your effort.
here is the 
MainActivity code..

Button btnSave, btnEdit;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSave= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    btnEdit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEdit);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, InsertItem.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateItem.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

This is updateActivity..

```
Button btnUpdate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_item);


    btnUpdate=findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(UpdateItem.this,"Update Item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

SaveActivity code....

Button btnApply;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_item);




    btnApply= findViewById(R.id.buttonApply);
    btnApply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(InsertItem.this,"Item Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You want to store user input in `EditText` into `ArrayList`?

Comment: exactly thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what do you mean by saying "use the EditText to list a list of items", but you're probably looking for [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView), where you can set your array of items in an adapter and then display them in a list form.

You can then modify the ArrayList by putting a new item or getting the item you want to edit by using [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener).

EDIT:

For inserting an item

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            arrayList.add(valueFromEditText); // add element to arrayList
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // refresh the adapter
        }
    });
```

Hope I could help you somehow :)

Comment: would you care to share the code for this? i mean the adapter.

Comment: From the info you gave, I can't really tell more, so please check the link attached to AutoCompleteTextView. You can find the basic code there which should be sufficient.

Comment: now i want to create an arrayList where i can save the user input and can search it later?

Comment: see the edit, but you should create another editText for providing new values, as AutoCompleteTextView display only values that are present in your arrayList